# Is $N_{A_7}(H) = H$, with the following $H$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

I am following a proof in which I have a subgroup of $S_7$ defined by

$H := \langle (2, 3, 4)(5, 6, 7) , (2, 7, 6, 3)(4, 5) \rangle$

The book implicitly uses that $N_{A_7}(H) = H$ (the normalizer of $H$ in $A_7$). I have checked it with GAP, but I would like to know if there is a trivial or simple way to see this, because the book doesn't even bother to say it is trivial (so the author thought it was more than trivial). I haven't found a simple way to do it.

Comment: The order is 24. It is transitive, for if it is of any help. And isomorphic to $S_4$

Comment: It is not transitive as $1$ is fixed by $H$.

Comment: Typo, sorry: it is transitive in the six symbols that it displaces

Comment: Then the problem is equivalent to proving that it is self-normalizing in $A_6$. If not the normalizer would have index $1,3$ or $5$ in $A_6$, which is not possible because $A_6$ is simple.

Comment: So this reduces to a question about $A_6$, in which $H$ has index $15=3\times5$. But $A_6$ has no subgroups of index $3$ or $5$, and $A_6$ is simple.